# How can I verify if record with particular key_name already exists in the datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I need to add products to my datastore. In case if product already exists, then I need to assign another `key_name`.
Let's say, I already have:
product = MyDBModelProduct(key_name='milk')
now when I add another products (milk again), I need to have them added with key_names milk-1, milk-2, milk-3 and so on.
So, before adding new db record, I need to verify if milk is already there.
I see 3 possible ways to do so:

(1) `GqlQuery` usage:

```
proposed_key_name = 'milk'
product = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM MyDBModelProduct WHERE key_name = :1 LIMIT 1", proposed_key_name).fetch(1)
if (len(product) > 0): # can not use this name, should look for milk-2, milk-3...
```

(2) `all` usage:

```
query = MyDBModelProduct.all()
count = query.filter('key_name =', proposed_key_name).count()
```

(3) `get_by_key_name` usage:

```
id_key_name = proposed_key_name
id_count = 1
while MyDBModelProduct.get_by_key_name(id_key_name) is not None:
    id_key_name = proposed_key_name + '-' + id_count
    id_count += 1
```

What is the best approach? Which one will work faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Options 1 and 2 are identical. Neither will work, because `key_name` is not a valid filter - instead you need to construct a fully qualified key and query on it - eg, `.filter('__key__ =', my_key)`.  You should also do a keys-only query - `SELECT __key__` or `MyDBModelProduct.all(keys_only=True)`, since you don't need the actual model entity.

Number 3 is faster than 1 and 2 as they stand, but if you modify the query as described above, 1 or 2 are faster. If you need to do this in bulk, `get`/`get_by_key_name` support batch operations, whilst `Query` does not.

Your proposed usage is rather perplexing, though - the whole point of key names are to use a natural key that has some external meaning, but you're inventing new ones depending on whether the existing one is used already.